# How to increment/decrement a random (type 4) UUID?

Tags: algorithm, cassandra, guid, uuid

How can I implement a function increment(uuid) that given version 4 UUID A produces a **valid** version 4 UUID B where:

1. B > A
2. There exists NO C where B > C > A

And the same for decrement(uuid) that given version 4 UUID A produces a **valid** version 4 UUID B where:

1. B < A
2. There exists NO C where B < C < A

Comment: Why are you comparing GUIDs using anything other than `==` or `!=`?  They're not really supposed to have any relationship to each other other than that...

Comment: Add to that, coming up with a new UUID that's "greater" than a given one, is not always possible.  Consider a UUID ffff...ffff.  What should increment(that UUID) return?  Even where it's possible, arbitrarily restricting the range will make collisions far more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python function to achieve what you want:

```
def increment_uuid(uuid, increment):
    # Return a UUID value incremented by an integer

    hex_str = uuid[:8] + uuid[9:13] + uuid[14:18] + uuid[19:23] + uuid[24:]
    incremented_val = int(hex_str, 16) + increment
    assert(incremented_val >= 0 and incremented_val <= 2 ** 128)
    incremented_hex = format(incremented_val, '032x')
    incrmented_uuid = incremented_hex[:8] + '-' + incremented_hex[8:12] + '-' + incremented_hex[12:16] \
                      + '-' + incremented_hex[16:20] + '-' + incremented_hex[20:]
    return incrmented_uuid
```

You can now simply increment a UUID by 1 to get the next one in the 'sequence':

```
import uuid
uuid_a = uuid.uuid4() # e.g. a32258b5-2781-44ec-9e00-f4b1185e9936
uuid_b = increment_uuid(str(uuid_a),1) # e.g. a32258b5-2781-44ec-9e00-f4b1185e9937
```

Of course, it simply treats the data as a 128-bit hex value, and disregards the constraints on the version number and variant bits.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  With the exception of the 6-bits reserved for the version and variant fields, v4 UUIDs consist of completely random data - i.e. there is no inherent notion of "sequence" within which to define meaningful increment / decrement operations.